# RuntimeError: Too early to create image

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create an image library and to call an image from that image library in `tkinter`.  But this code gives me an error:

This is the image library file `img.py`:

```
from tkinter import *
food_0001 = PhotoImage(file='food_0001.gif')
food_0002 = PhotoImage(file='bg.gif')
```

This is the file intended to open images stored in `img.py`:

```
from tkinter import *
import img

window = Tk()
window.title('image')
canvas = Canvas(window, width = 800, height = 800)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=food_0001)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `PhotoImage()` can only be called after creation of `Tk()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Can you make that an answer?

Answer (score 8):

It is because `PhotoImage()` can only be called after creation of `Tk()`.

Suggest to rewrite `img.py` to create `PhotoImage()` only when it is needed.  Below is a sample way to do it:

```
from tkinter import *

imagelist = {
  'food_0001': ['food_0001.png', None],
  'food_0002': ['bg.png', None],
}

def get(name):
  if name in imagelist:
    if imagelist[name][1] is None:
      print('loading image:', name)
      imagelist[name][1] = PhotoImage(file=imagelist[name][0])
    return imagelist[name][1]
  return None
```

Then modify your main program to cater the change:

```
from tkinter import *
import img

window = Tk()
window.title('image')
canvas = Canvas(window, width=800, height=800)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=img.get('food_0001'))

window.mainloop()
```

Of cause there are many other ways to do it and it depends on your imagination.